# Is it possible to make a custom implementation of ViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

Asp.Net has some options to influence the ways a page its ViewState is generated (encryption, adding of a mac, ViewStateUserKey).

I would like to do it myself, not based on configuration, but on my own class that used other algorithms for serialization and encryption. Is this possible?

Comment: What's your goal here? I've had to work with custom viewstate providers that people have built, and the only thing it did for me was make me want to strangle the guy for not following any known standards.

Comment: @JoeEnos the ViewState should be black box right? Right now I'm willing to strangle Asp.Net for not playing nice with my `Server.TransferRequests`. I need to set some application level security settings. Now my security is set by the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. For instance, I built a view state compression logic based on some articles you can find on CodeProject. You'll need to override `PageStatePersister` from `Page` and create a class derivated from `PageStatePersister`:

```
// In your page:
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
   get { return new ViewStateCompressor(this); }
}
```

And create a new class:

```
public class ViewStateCompressor : PageStatePersister
{
    private const string ViewStateKey   = "__VSTATE";
    public ViewStateCompressor(Page page) : base(page)
    {
    }

    private LosFormatter stateFormatter;
    protected new LosFormatter StateFormatter
    {
        get { return this.stateFormatter ?? (this.stateFormatter = new LosFormatter()); }
    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            // Put viewstate data on writer
            StateFormatter.Serialize(writer, new Pair(base.ViewState, base.ControlState));

            // Handle your viewstate data
            // byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(writer.ToString());

            // Here I create another hidden field named "__VSTATE"
            ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(Page, ViewStateKey, Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray()));
        }
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base.Page.Request.Form[ViewStateKey]);
        using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            input.Position = 0;

            // Handle your viewstate data

            Pair p = ((Pair)(StateFormatter.Deserialize(Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray()))));
            base.ViewState = p.First;
            base.ControlState = p.Second;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. What does this class do different from the .Net implementation? Does .Net handle the encryption of the value or can I handle it myself?

Comment: Once you get that `StateFormatter.Serialize`, you'll have viewstate content and you can handle it in any way you need. In my case, I just compact with some zip library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to implement your own [PageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. The MSDN page shows you an example of how it works.

We had a rather large ViewState we offloaded to the file system and replaced it with a much more compact GUID on the actual page.