# Simulate previous request

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, httpresponse

In my application there are sometimes in that I want to get a user request, save it in some place and then, in a next request, simulate saved request instead of real request, is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to do this all in your application, or are you just debugging an issue?

Comment: Ah. are you using MVC or WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

Use any web debugger. I use Fiddler 2.6.2 myself.

Find it here, https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Be warned - there is no robust way to do it (there are a lot of edge cases to consider) but hopefully this will get you started:

1. Take `Request.Form.ToString()` and save it against the user somewhere. For testing I suggest putting it in a hidden field, but at some point you would probably need to move that to a database and associate that with the user somehow.
2. You will need to have a field that will tell you whether the previous request should be replayed. Using a query string parameter like `?replay=true` will work. Then pull it into your page:

   ```
   protected bool IsReplayRequest
   {
       get 
       {
           return bool.Parse(this.GetValue(p => p.Request["replay"], "false"));
       }
   }
   ```
3. To simulate the request you will need to override the page's `DeterminePostBackMode`. This is one of the first methods ASP.NET calls to start the postback process. Use the saved request form converted into a `NameValueCollection`. Something like this:

   ```
   protected override NameValueCollection DeterminePostBackMode()
   {
       if (IsReplayRequest && SavedFormData != null)
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SavedFormData.Data))
           {
               return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(SavedFormData.Data ?? string.Empty);
           }
       }

       return base.DeterminePostBackMode();
   }
   ```

Where `SavedFormData` is just a class which holds the request form and the user information.

With those 3 steps, you should be able to succesfully simulate a previous request for a simple page

---

Now for the potential problems:

First, the viewstate might get in the way. If you have any listboxes or data grids or authentication etc, you will then need to save the viewstate with the form data. for that you will need to override the page `GetStatePersister()` method ([Is it possible to make a custom implementation of ViewState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124719/is-it-possible-to-make-a-custom-implementation-of-viewstate)).

Second, once you have simulated a request, you need to make sure a) no data is corrupted and b) you remove the "replay" query string. Otherwise the request will play over and over again.

Third, depending on how you store the request form, you will have to think about how to associate it with the user/browser/session/window. Dealing with each one of those has it's own problems.

---

Once you've got everything above solved, you will successfully simulate a saved request!